# getStringArrayListExtra on Intent in Titanium (Appcelerator)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

In order to use the speech recognition intent on Android, I need to be able to call `getStringArrayListExtra` on the intent in the activity result callback.  Unfortunately, it looks like Titanium doesn't have a wrapper for this method in its [Intent class](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.2/Titanium.Android.Intent-object).  Does anyone know how I can go about getting this data despite this method not existing?

Here's my code:

```
  var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: FOTT.VoiceRecognizer.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH
  });

  /* ...snip... */

  Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(event) {
    if (event.resultCode == Ti.Android.RESULT_OK) {
      var results = event.intent.getStringArrayListExtra("android.speech.extra.RESULTS");
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Titanium's Intent Proxy does not include a wrapper for this method.  As such, I wrote a [custom module](https://github.com/mhuggins/intent) to solve the problem.